# Difference of date in Hours in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I wanted to Get the Difference in Hours in Oracle SQL.

Example/Expected Output:

```
10/10/2019 12:00:00 - 10/09/2019 10:00:00 PM **= 2 Hours**

For Days it could be 0.08
```

Here is the DB Fiddle, I know to get the days, Could you help me out to calculate hours?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da2b689bfde9b3ede55eb5c6ae15fcc5

Comment: What are the inputs? You say "time stamps" in your title, but the example seems to have the values in **date** data type, which is different from **timestamp**.

Comment: In any case, to calculate the hours multiply the days by 24. Right?

Comment: Your db fiddlde does not really relate to your question.

Comment: My DB fiddle has the values in days, needed it in hours. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76073eadf727da5c713d37cae669117e   How ever I am not sure about KEY = 2

Comment: As explained by @mathguy, substracting dates gives you a result in days. Just multiply that by 24 to get the results in hours.

Comment: `SELECT 
    (
        TO_DATE('10/10/2019 12:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
        - TO_DATE('10/10/2019 10:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    ) * 24 diff_hours
FROM DUAL` yields : `2`

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer

Comment: Welcome @StackOne. Closing this question as duplicate.